# Geth - Events not working/firing

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, parity, nodejs

I have an API (expressjs - nodejs) listening for different events from my contract.

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:8546"));
var tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenAbi, URL.tokenAddress);

tokenContract.events.EventTest({
    fromBlock: 'latest'
}, function (err, event) {
   console.log('event triggered');
});
```

For this, I need a provider. When I'm using parity:

```
parity --chain ropsten
```

Everything works fine.

But when I try with Geth, I NEVER received events from my contract:

```
geth --testnet --ws --wsport=8546 --wsorigins="*"
```

I'm well connected to the network because :

```
web3.eth.net.getId().then(function (id) {
     console.log('ID network chain', id);
});
```

Return me the id `3`.

Do I miss something? 
Thank you in advance.